# Display another method value to another method

Tags: java, methods, parameters

There are three class **Main class, Calc class and Result class**;I want to get calcSum() return value to Result class, result() method; but it shows 0.
what is the problem?

**Calc Class**

```
public class Calc {

    public int calcSum(int x,int y){

        int s = x+ y;

        System.out.println("output "+s);

        return s;
    }
}
```

**Result Class**

```
public class Result {

   public void result(){

       Calc res = new Calc();
       int x=0;int y = 0;

       int r = res.calcSum(x,y);
       System.out.println("Result class: "+r);
   }

}
```

**Main class**

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        Result s = new Result();
        Calc n = new Calc();
        n.calcSum(10,10);
        s.result();
    }

}
```

[**Output**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2IQFJ.png)

***Result class: 0***

Comment: Because you are calling `s` result.

Comment: Because 0 + 0 = 0.

Comment: Read through your code step by step, or even better, use a debugger. When you call `s.result()`, you then pass 0 and 0 to `calcSum` which obviously adds up to 0.

Comment: its correct; I called same method twice (main method and result method..) i think thats the problem, but I want to know how to get that value. someone know another way to get that.

Comment: `n.calcSum(10,10);` Here you sum 10+10 and then ignore the result

Answer (score 0):

To get  `20` you need to use the result of `n.calcSum(10,10);` but you never assign it to a variable :

```
n.calcSum(10,10);
```

In fact the `Result` class seems useless and looks like more a case of example as it hardcodes a invocation of `calculSum()` with `0` and `0`.  Whereas the result in the output: `0`.

The `Calc` class seems enough to accomplish your logical :

```
Calc n = new Calc();
System.out.println("result="+ n.calcSum(10,10));
```

The `Result` class would make sense if you would return a custom object in `Calc.calcSum()` but actually it is not the case : an `int` is returned.